# Apply Css styling in Vaadin application

Tags: css, gwt, resources, vaadin

I am trying to apply normal `Css` fomating in a `Vaadin 7` application (I am new in Vaadin) and I can not get it work properly. In partucular I want to use the method `addStyleName()` on a Table like in `GWT`:

```
Table table = new Table("Films");
table.addStyleName("test");
```

My problem is that I do not know precicely where to put the .css file and how to "inject" it. I have followed the instructions of the [Vaadin Book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html) and of the first answer of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511560/how-do-i-use-css-to-style-my-form-components) but in my project it does not work. There is no folder `VAADIN` under WebContent. I create the folder `VAADIN/Themes/mytheme` and I create the file `mytheme.css` and styles.css in it. I am not sure if I need a custom file `styles.css` (probably the problem come from that). The file `mytheme.css` looks like:

```
@import "../reindeer/styles.css";

.test{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

and the file `styles.css` is empty. In the application class I use the annotation:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyprojectUI extends UI {
...
}
```

However it does not work. Not only the "test" css class is not applied but the standard css style of the `UI` is lost (a white page with black letters).
I receive also the warning:

```
Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
Jun 12, 2013 8:44:44 PM com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
```

Ok, it does not find the theme jar. What is wrong, since the instructions do not indicate something different. Maybe the

```
@import "../reindeer/styles.css";
```

?

**UPDATE:** It is the same problem as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561633/vaadin-cannot-find-themes-when-in-productionmode?rq=1) but I do not use maven. What should be done in this occassion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It seems to me a little bit peculiar, but the project tries always to find a `styles.css` file in the Theme folder when someone creates a new Theme. The `styles.css` file should not be empty, but it should import the `mytheme.css`. Finaly the css files are:

mytheme.css:

```
@import "../reindeer/legacy-styles.css";
@import "../reindeer/styles.css";

.test{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

styles.css:

```
@import "mytheme.css";
```

The `legacy-styles.css` and `styles.css` files are included in the `vaadin.themes` jar.

Comment: mythemes.css should not import "../reindeer/styles.css"

Answer (score 0):

You were right creating the folders VAADIN/themes/mytheme.
Create there a css file named styles.css and add `@import "../reindeer/legacy-styles.css";`

Now you shouldn't get a "Requested resource no found" exception.

In your file VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css you can override or define new css-classes.

If you want to add a style name to the table, like "myColor", you have to define it in your styles.css like this:

```
.v-table-myColor { color: red; }
```

and add it to the table: `table.addStyleName("myColor");`

More info about CSS Style Rules for the table [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.css).

Comment: with Vaadin 7 and pure CSS one should import "../reindeer/legacy-styles.css" not styles.css